# Using pd.concat to replicate pd.merge Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

Let's say I have 3 `df` such as the ones below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Week': ['W1', 'W2', 'W3', 'W4', 'W5', 'W6', 'W7'], 'A': [34, 67, 92, 31, 90, 100, 101]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Week': ['W4', 'W5', 'W6', 'W7', 'W8', 'W9', 'W10'], 'B': [75, np.nan, 53, 21, 94, 47, 88]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Week': ['W12', 'W13', 'W14', 'W15', 'W16', 'W17', 'W18'], 'C': [25, 30, 40, 45, 46, 47, 48]})
```

Normally when I am building my database of stock prices I would use `pd.merge` and use the very helpful `on='Week'` (in this instance) function to merge the dataframes together using the Week column. So my code would be something like this:

```
df = pd.merge(df, df2, on='Week', how='left')
df = pd.merge(df, df3, on='Week', how='left')
```

Producing the following `df`:

```
  Week    A     B   C
0   W1   34   NaN NaN
1   W2   67   NaN NaN
2   W3   92   NaN NaN
3   W4   31  75.0 NaN
4   W5   90   NaN NaN
5   W6  100  53.0 NaN
6   W7  101  21.0 NaN
```

This is perfect, I only want to see data for W1 - W7, if there's no data I just want NaNs.

I'm led to believe that using `pd.concat` is much faster than `pd.merge` and as I am looking at hundreds of stocks this could really help reduce the time it takes to build my `df`. But it's really important of course that the dates should match exactly, hence why I have been using the `on=` function in `pd.merge`.

I can't so far work out how to replicate this behaviour using `pd.concat`. Does anyone have any suggestions? The sort of thing I have tried so far looks like this:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df2], sort=True).groupby('Week').mean()
```

But this results in the following, which isn't even close to what I want:

```
          A     B
Week             
W1     34.0   NaN
W10     NaN  88.0
W2     67.0   NaN
W3     92.0   NaN
W4     31.0  75.0
W5     90.0   NaN
W6    100.0  53.0
W7    101.0  21.0
W8      NaN  94.0
W9      NaN  47.0
```

Any help would be really appreciated, cheers

EDIT:

Sorry, just to clarify, my expected output is the `df` halfway down, this one:

```
  Week    A     B   C
0   W1   34   NaN NaN
1   W2   67   NaN NaN
2   W3   92   NaN NaN
3   W4   31  75.0 NaN
4   W5   90   NaN NaN
5   W6  100  53.0 NaN
6   W7  101  21.0 NaN
```

Comment: so what is your expected output ?

Comment: Hi mate, fair point, have just edited the question, cheers

Comment: why arent you concatenating df3?

Comment: I was just trying to show that what I was attempting so far wasn't working, I've only been playing around with concat so far and can't get anywhere

Comment: I do not think `pd.concat` is the right choice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
concated = pd.concat([df, df2, df3], sort=False).groupby('Week').first()
result = concated[concated.index.isin(('W1', 'W2', 'W3', 'W4', 'W5', 'W6', 'W7'))]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
          A     B   C
Week                 
W1     34.0   NaN NaN
W2     67.0   NaN NaN
W3     92.0   NaN NaN
W4     31.0  75.0 NaN
W5     90.0   NaN NaN
W6    100.0  53.0 NaN
W7    101.0  21.0 NaN
```

Comment: Hi mate thats a really good answer, will have a play around with it thanks

Comment: @topbantz Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd just chain the merge method because it's more concise and the speed difference isn't noticeable unless you have massive data.

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='left').merge(df3, how='left')
print(df)

  Week    A     B   C
0   W1   34   NaN NaN
1   W2   67   NaN NaN
2   W3   92   NaN NaN
3   W4   31  75.0 NaN
4   W5   90   NaN NaN
5   W6  100  53.0 NaN
6   W7  101  21.0 NaN
```